# Is there a true quick sort algorithm for C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

edit: The OP's confusion [resulted from assuming the pivot had fixed position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655257/is-there-a-true-quick-sort-algorithm-for-c#comment53158386_32655415).  It actually moves depending on how many elements are <= to it.  It didn't help that one of the examples chooses `7` as a pivot element, ends up swapping it to a higher index, and finishing the first pass with a `7` from a different element in the position where the pivot started.

Ever since I learned about quick sort in CS and then started applying it with code, I have struggled with the concept that the code is executing a true quick sort algorithm.  The idea of quick sort is simple: a pivot from the original array is chosen, and all other numbers from the array are sorted to the left or right of that pivot.  Then each sub-array (items left of pivot and right of pivot) is sorted via the same method through a recursive call until the entire array is sorted.

In practice, every language I come across seems to have the same accepted general code to accomplish this.  It looks like this (from http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort):

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int i = left, j = right;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

      /* partition */
      while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                  tmp = arr[i];
                  arr[i] = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
            }
      };

      /* recursion */
      if (left < j)
            quickSort(arr, left, j);
      if (i < right)
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

However, as you can see from the website's own visual, when the first partition is stopped, a '3' is still to the right of the chosen '7' pivot.  I have also observed this when testing other arrays.  For [6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2], the first pivot is 8.  After the first partition, 8 ends up to the right of the 9 all the way until the last recursive call.  Has anyone noticed this before?

Comment: What is the question here, again?

Comment: If the code you posted does not implement quicksort, then it does not implement quicksort. vOv And of course one can implement quicksort in C++. I do not understand the question at hand.

Comment: Do you agree that this is not performing the theoretical quick sort algorithm because all elements to the left and right of the pivot are not sorted correctly before the recursive call?

Comment: Maybe I should change my question to:  Is there code that performs a quick sort better than what's above?

Comment: @apdm How would they be sorted correctly before the recursive call? The recursive call is what sorts them correctly.

Comment: What is "better" ? Faster? In less memory? In less lines of code? More enthusiastic?

Comment: @Barry - OP suggests the linked site shows the array isn't _partitioned_ correctly before the recursive call.

Comment: @Barry: The OP seems to be focusing on the fact that the given algorithm partitions into `<= pivot | >= pivot` rather than `<= pivot | pivot | >= pivot`.

Comment: Yeah ouch, I had no idea this would be received so harshly

Comment: @EugeneSh. Needs more ASCII art obv. ASCII art makes any piece of code better.

Comment: @Hurkyl is correct.  That was what I was trying to ask, thanks

Comment: @Useless It *is* partitioned correctly. We end up with two sections, one with values `<= 7` and one with values `>= 7`.

Comment: IIRC, no existing C++ implementation uses QuickSort anyway. It's suboptimal for certain common edge cases (1 element misplaced, for instance).

Comment: @mwigdahl this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Hmmm.  Not being a heavy user of Programmers.SE I'll defer to your judgment, but it seems to at least be topical under the "algorithm and data structure concepts" category.  Point well taken that a vague question on SO is probably not going to go well on Programmers.SE though.

Comment: @mwigdahl It's definitely *on-topic* for Programmers, but being a good question is about more than just being on-topic. If the question is unclear on this site, moving it to Programmers does not magically make it more clear. Migration can only change whether a question is on-topic, not whether that question is well-written/well-asked.

Answer (score 10):

> However, as you can see from the website's own visual, when the first partition is stopped, a '3' is still to the right of the chosen '7' pivot

Partition moves everything such that `left <= 7 <= right`, which the algorithm presented does:

```
1 2 5 7 3 | 14 7 26 12
```

The chosen pivot is not the **array element** `7`, but the **value** 7.

Think of the pivot as a **value**, not as an element of the array. That is what the theory says, and the website you linked to says it too:

> Choose a pivot value. We take the value of the middle element as pivot value, **but it can be any value, which is in range of sorted values, even if it doesn't present in the array**.

Choosing the value of an element is just a convenience. If you replace the "|" above with `7`, the algorithm fits the theory.

Quicksort **can** also be implemented as `left | pivot | right`, for example see the first pseudocode on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). It doesn't **have** to be though, and `left <= pivot | pivot | right >= pivot` is a subset of `left <= pivot | right >= pivot`. So if you do the first, you actually do the second as well.

Comment: Actually, I'm still not sure this holds up with the following array     
    [6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 2].  
First partition results in
    6 5 1 3 2 |  4 7 9 8

Comment: @apdm are you sure? Did you get that from running the code?

Comment: That should pick `8` as the pivot value. I think you probably made a mistake in placing the `|`?

Comment: For the end result is does not matter where the pivot goes - left, right, or in between - because it will be sorted later. But the intermediate results obviously will differ. Also, the correct versions would have to be `left < pivot | pivot | pivot < right` and `left < pivot | pivot <= right`

Comment: @apdm No, the partition results are 6 5 1 3 2 4 7 | 9 8. The placement of the `|` matters.

Comment: @MSalters What if all of your array elements are equal? How are you going to get `left < pivot | pivot | pivot < right`? I'm not sure I understand what you're saying apdm is correct about.

Comment: @IVlad: If you do implement it that way, the middle part (==pivot) can indeed be a repeated element (Or at least a set of equivalent elements). For that reason you don't need to sort them. It's slightly more convenient to not have that third middle set,

Comment: @Barry I'm sorry, how are you choosing where the `|` goes?  In the original answer from IVlad it is left in it's original pivot place

Comment: @apdm: I ran [your partition code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/xpmbSp), note the ending values of `i` and `j`. It looks correct to me. The resulting partitions don't have to be identical to their positions/sizes before partitioning.

Comment: @apdm: The place where `|` goes is fully determined by the count of elements smaller than the pivot.

Comment: @MSalters Right.  I realized that question didn't make much sense after I submitted it

Comment: @Blastfurnace so the `|` is always right after `i` ?

Comment: @apdm: In this implementation `i` and `j` cross over each other. The recursive calls are done on the ranges `[left, j]` and `[i, right]`

Comment: @apdm That's what the algorithm does. The `|` goes where `i` and `j` end up after the partition loop.